# How to use find objects in multiple levels of nested arrays

Tags: javascript

What I want is to find an object in a nested array, and to get it by a pre-known `ScheduleId` number, and where the `Duration` property is defined.

We need to find this element which is contained inside of array of `"Columns"`, and `"Columns"` are contained within `"Table"` elements.

After finding this object, I want to update `ScheduleId = 0` and `Duration = 0`.

Sample data:

```
var data = {
    "Headers": [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C",
        "D"
    ],
    "Table": [
        {
            "Columns": [
                {
                    "Duration": 0,
                    "ScheduleId": 12,
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            "Columns": [
                {
                    "Duration": 22,
                    "ScheduleId": 44,
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            "Columns": [
                {
                    "Duration": 0,
                    "ScheduleId": 1648,
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            "Columns": [
                {
                    "Duration": 0,
                    "ScheduleId": 22,
                },
            ],
        },
    ]
};
```

Pseudo code:

```
var requestedScheduleId = 22;
var requestedObj = data.Table.find(x => requestedScheduleId.Equals(x.Columns.ScheduleId) )
requestedObj.ScheduleId = 0;
requestedScheduleId.Duration = 0;
```

Unsuccessful attempt:

```
var test = data.Table.map(({ Columns }) => {return Columns = Columns.filter(({ ScheduleId }) => ScheduleId == 22 )});

console.log(test);
```

Comment: Please include your code in your post, rather than a link to elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use `.map` or `.filter` for this. It's a plain and simple nested loop: For each table, for each column, if condition is met, do something.

Either with `for` loops:

```
for (table of data.Table) {
    for (column of table.Columns) {
        if (column.ScheduleId === 22) {
            column.ScheduleId = 0;
            column.Duration = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

or with `Array#forEach`:

```
data.Table.forEach(table => {
    table.Columns.forEach(column => {
        if (column.ScheduleId === 22) {
            column.ScheduleId = 0;
            column.Duration = 0;
        }
    });
});
```

```js
var data = {
    "Headers": [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C",
        "D"
    ],
    "Table": [
        {
            "Columns": [
                {
                    "Duration": 0,
                    "ScheduleId": 12,
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            "Columns": [
                {
                    "Duration": 22,
                    "ScheduleId": 44,
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            "Columns": [
                {
                    "Duration": 0,
                    "ScheduleId": 1648,
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            "Columns": [
                {
                    "Duration": 0,
                    "ScheduleId": 22,
                },
            ],
        },
    ]
};

var requestedScheduleId = 22;

data.Table.forEach(table => {
    table.Columns.forEach(column => {
        if (column.ScheduleId === requestedScheduleId) {
            column.ScheduleId = 0;
            column.Duration = 0;
        }
    });
});

console.log(data);
```